# Should I explicitly delete object with custom format from clipboard?

Tags: windows, winapi, clipboard

I have following question - should I delete explicitly object placed in windows clipboard? What does `EmptyClipboard` function in such case? Global object was created via `GlobalAlloc` function, and has custom format (which was registered via `RegisterClipboardFormat` function). I did not find section which says about such aspect

Answer (score 1):

No, once you place the object on the clipboard, the clipboard is responsible for destroying it. You allocated the memory with `GlobalAlloc`, as required, and the system is therefore able to deallocate the memory using `GlobalFree`. Which is does when it needs to.